# How is Section 31 funded?

Tags: star-trek, section-31

How is Section 31 funded? In Star Trek, money doesn't really exist, although there seems to be a finite limit to star ship production.

Comment: There's no money in the Federation!  Obviously, Section 31 runs on narrativium.

Comment: They hold the patent to Velcro.

Comment: Which iteration?  The one we're introduced to in DS9 is quite different than the one from the Kelvin timeline (and DIS, if that's what those black badges mean)

Comment: The truth is that we don't actually know anything comprehensive about 23rd or 24th century economy in Star Trek. The narrative hints we've been given over the years are actually horribly contradictory. The reason for this is simple: Star Trek is not about the Federation's economy!

Comment: Free energy = free everything else, like everything else in the Federation.

Comment: Nobody knows - section 31 is so secret nobody outside it knows they exist, let alone where they secretly get their money and/or supplies from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Section 31 is an autonomous clandestine organization, meaning they get their own resources by their own means.

Think of it as the clandestine part of CIA or any other similar agencies. CIA is founded by the government but also has clandestine $-producing ops of it's own, as it has been proven over and over again.

As Solan implies, S31 has sufficient contacts within Starfleet to access required resources and equipment when the situation demands it.

Also note, that excessive starship production from them would significantly increase the risk of S31's activities being discovered on a sufficiently large scale so that the Federation would of been obliged to take an official position regarding them.